# JavaScript not changing width (with Google website translate)

Tags: javascript

I'm using Google translate and I'm altering it a bit. Now I'm having a weird problem. It doesn't work.

JavaScript Code

```js
var setWidthgoog = $(".goog-te-gadget-simple").width();
$(".google-t").css({"width": (setWidthgoog) + 'px'});
```

HTML code

```html
<div class="google-t">
  <div id="google_translate_element">
    <div class="skiptranslate goog-te-gadget" dir="ltr">
      <div id=":0.targetLanguage" class="goog-te-gadget-simple" style="white-space: nowrap;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I put the same code in the console it works...
[image]

Thoughts?

The google translate im refering is this (the website plugin)
http://translate.google.com/manager/website/

**EDIT**
Thanks to War10ck i discover that the plugin is only called after aprox. 2s, is there anyway to make it to call faster?

Comment: What has this got to do with google translate?

Comment: Test with a settimeout, maybe someother code wants to override and might be after your code

Comment: I think he means he has written the post using google translator

Comment: This google translate:
http://translate.google.com/manager/website/

Comment: Since this is an external widget, Google may be loading it asynchronously. Before your code above add: `console.log($('.goog-te-gadget-simple').length); console.log($('.google-t').length);`... If these report `0` in the console, then the elements are not yet on the page when your code is running.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish and what is the issue your having. Perhaps you should try to describe it more.
You are using those embeddable bars from google translate that you add to you own site?

Comment: What im trying to accomplish is to center the select language box in my site,  i have absolute positions in al my index page (necessary :P) and to center correctly the object i want to determine the width of said object to then, with margin:auto, center it on my page

Answer (score 0):

> Test with a settimeout, maybe someother code wants to override and
>   might be after your code

– [joyBlanks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4283738/joyblanks)

That actually worked!, tough i don't know what the google plugin may be calling after my code :S

Comment: It could be an overwrite. It could also be an async issue where the content is not yet present when the page loads but it is after the timeout. `$(selector).length` is a good way of determining this. The jQuery object returns an array of matched selectors or an empty array if no matches are found. Check the length property of this array using the above syntax to rule out the async issue.

Comment: the google object ".goog-te-gadget-simple" is 0 when my google-t class is 1… so somehow the object doesn't appear after aprox. 2s.

Comment: That's an async problem then. Since the element is not present when your script is executing the `width` value is not received or is recorded as `0` (not sure which).